# Duplicate rows when using %in% on R data table

Tags: r, data.table

Example:

```
test <- data.table(id=c(rep(1,3), 2:4), col1=1:6)
ids <- c(1,10,1)
test[id %in% ids]
```

Outputs:

```
   id col1
1:  1    1
2:  1    2
3:  1    3
4:  1    1
5:  1    2
6:  1    3
```

I would expect that the output would be:

```
   id col1
1:  1    1
2:  1    2
3:  1    3
```

I see that the fix is to use `test[id %in% unique(ids)]`. My question is: why does the subsetting act in this way? The cause seems to be the duplicate value in the `ids` vector, but I'd like to know why `data.table` acts in this manner for this particular case.

Thanks!

EDIT:
In data.table version 1.9.4 (current CRAN version), `test[(id %in% ids)]` produces the expected output, or by setting `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`. In data.table version 1.9.5, `test[id %in% ids]` produces the expected output.

This is a bug in version 1.9.4 of data.table, bug fixes #6, github.com/Rdatatable/data.table. Thanks to @nongkrong and @Frank for their comments.

Comment: it outputs as expected for me, maybe has something to do with using the devel version

Comment: I'm using R version 3.2.1 with data.table_1.9.4 with some packages loaded via namespace (plyr_1.8.3, reshape2_1.4, Rcpp_0.11.6, stringr_0.6.2, chron_2.3-45). It's possible that it's due to a conflict with one of these. What version are you running @nongkrong?

Comment: data.table_1.9.5, https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: Yes, I see what the OP sees. On 1.9.4, gotta add parens `test[(id %in% ids)]`

Comment: I can confirm that with data.table_1.9.5 from the github repo that the expected output is indeed what comes out of `test[id %in% ids]`. Will update OP.

Comment: @Frank yea its under bug fixes #6, https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Or set `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`